# I want to get rid of extra space in list group

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to learn how to construct a sidebar.

I get an unwanted rectangular area under item 3 when it is expanded.

I want to get rid of this blank rectangular area.

I have not added any padding in the code, there is no CSS. I tried to do a browser inspect, but did not get to fix it.

I want to remove this blank rectangular area.

Thanks.

The code is here (also referenced in the link below):

```
      <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
                   Item 1</a>
        <a ref="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
                   Item 2</a>
        <a href="#IDp_3" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" 
           data-toggle="collapse"
           onclick=" $('#PM0001').toggleClass('fa-minus-square fa-plus-square')">
           <i class="fas fa fa-plus-square" id="PM0001" ></i>
                    Item 3                                      
           <div class="collapse" id="IDp_3">
           <a href="" class="list-group-item">
                   -3.1</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">
                   -3.2</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">
                   -3.3</a>
      </div?
    <div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle code with problem.](https://jsfiddle.net/ekareem/aq9Laaew/249956/)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the anchor after Item 3

```
<a href="#p_3" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-toggle="collapse"  onclick=" $('#PM0001').toggleClass('fa-minus-square fa-plus-square')">
                    <i class="fas fa fa-plus-square" id="PM0001" ></i>
                        Item 3
                        </a>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5vfxpt6b/

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there some kind of a way to debug the raw HTML and get simple to read result?

Comment: I mean a line number of where the problem is and a meaningful message.

Comment: There are a few extensions for Chrome and Firefox that might be helpful, look for html validators. Or there are some online tools like this one: https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 1):

its because you didn't close you 3rd anchor.

## Code: No Closing tag.

```
  <a href="#p_3" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-toggle="collapse"
                    onclick=" $('#PM0001').toggleClass('fa-minus-square fa-plus-square')">
                    <i class="fas fa fa-plus-square" id="PM0001" ></i>
                        Item 3
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. You were first, but the other answer provided more clue, so I marked it as answer, it is hard to choose when one gets more than one answer.

Comment: @NoChance, there is no problem with that, Im glad that I helped you a litte bit. happy Coding!